# Добавление в данных в List<> Java

Tags: java, list

Есть такая конструкция:

```
List<String> altDN = new ArrayList<>();
```

В нее отлично добавляются данные с помощью кода:

```
altDN.add("CN=Test org1, SERIALNUMBER=1111111111");
```

Но я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы оно циклом добавляло более одной записи:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                altDN.add("CN=Test org%d, SERIALNUMBER=%d", i, rnd);
                           }
```

rnd генерируется. Подчеркивает ошибку в строке

```
altDN.add("CN=Test org%d, SERIALNUMBER=%d", i, rnd);
```

Как сделать?

Comment: Какого результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: Чтобы List заполнялся данными CN=Test org1, SERIALNUMBER=x, CN=Test org2, SERIALNUMBER=y, CN=Test org3, SERIALNUMBER=z и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `MessageFormat.format`

```
MessageFormat.format("CN=Test org{0}, SERIALNUMBER={1}", i, rnd);
```